# WPF Telerik Rad Map Polygon Data binding to Polygon Data within class

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I am trying to add polygons to the telerik rad map with a PolygonData class embedded within a parent class.

```
public class PolygonClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public PolygonData Polygon { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to bind my VisualizationLayer.ItemSource to the 'Polygon' Property within 'PolygonClass' because I need to reference an ID value in various other places of my application. The only way I've recently been able to make this work is by binding to a property of ObservableCollection.

Has anyone else ran into this and knows of a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? You want to bind it to a collection of the PolygonData for every PolygonClass that you have, but want to skip the Id?

Comment: Yeah so can just create an observablecollection to bind to but that wouldn't allow me to give an ID value to each polygon class.
If I remove the PolygonClass and just reference a property like:
public ObservableCollection<PolygonData> Polygon { get; set; }
It will work find but then I won't be able to reference an ID value for the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve your requirement.

You can populate the Items collection of VisualizaztionLayer (instead of ItemsSource) with PolygonData objects. Any additional information, like the the ID, can be stored in the ExtendedData property of the PolygonData.

```
PolygonData polygon = new PolygonData();
polygon.ExtendedData["ID"] = 3;
```

Or you can use the map bindable wrappers inside the ItemTemplate property of VisualizationLayer. In your case the wrapper that should be used is MapPolygonView.

```
<telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <telerik:MapPolygonView Points="{Binding Polygon.Points}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:VisualizationLayer.ItemTemplate>
```

Note that in this case, you won't need the PolygonData in your PolygonClass, because the MapPolygonView will automatically generate one and add in the VisualizationLayer. Instead, you can define the shape information (like points and fill) in PolygonClass and data bind to those.